# Misplaced button in dialog window of JqGrid, works fine while developers tools opened

Tags: css, jqgrid, console

The strangest behaviour occured and I can't handle it myself.

I have ASP .NET MVC application with Jqgrid version 5.1.0. Everything works fine, beside one dialog window.

In my grid I use default deletion method. There is delete button defined by `$(tableHtmlId).navGrid( ... )` function. After clicking delete button, confirmation dialog window appears. This dialog has misplaced cancel button (the one on top-right corner), as shown on following screen:

[image]

I thought about editing css styles, so I hit the console button, and as soon as develpers tool window appeard, look what happened:

[image]

Everything look fine. However, when I put cursor over cancel button, it goes back to wrong:

[image]

This behaviour occurs on Chrome, Firefox and IE. This bug is too atomic for me to solve. Please help. :)

Comment: Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.3. You need just change 3 lines of HTML code and to load jqGrid files from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). See [here](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code) an example of usage free jqGrid.

Comment: @Oleg the issue is which 3 lines of html and how to correct them ;)

Comment: How you included jqGrid on your HTML page? It's one line with `<link rel="stylesheet" href=".../ui.jqgrid.min.css">` (or `ui.jqgrid.css`), one line with  `<script src="...jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>` (or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`) and one more optional line with locale file like `<script src=".../i18n/grid.locale-de.min.js"></script>`. You should open the links from my previous comment and to see URLs which point to CDN location of the free jqGrid files.

Comment: @Oleg yes I did. Everything works and looks fine except this one bug. I have a big application with many grids and changing version of jqGrid seems a bit risky from my point of view.

Comment: It's your problem and your choice. I think you know that Guriddo jqGrid version 5.1.0 can't be used for free even if it's source code is open. If you paid for Guriddo (see [the prices](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) then you can get the corresponding support on [the Guriddo forum](http://guriddo.net/?forum=guriddo-js). I develop alternative fork of jqGrid which is further development of version 4.7 (the latest free version of jqGrid). The new features which I implemented are described in readmes to published version and in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki).

Comment: Ok I will check free jqGrid then